# Gambio: Usermod changes ignored

Tags: gambio

Using Gambio 4.7, I altered the homepage by creating an index-USERMOD.html file in the template folder (/templates/mytemplate/index-USERMOD.html). This has been working fine so far. Ever since the last major update to the current version of Gambio, I am not able to apply any other changes to the homepage.

- I manually cleared the cache
- I rename the smarty folder
- I cleared browser cache and wiped all cookies

Nonetheless, I can't get Gambio to show my latest changes to index-USERMOD.html
Any other hints of what I might have missed?